# Gitlab CI use ed25519 private key

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to do some stuff within Gitlab CI on a remote server. When using RSA keys everything works fine, but when I try using ED25519 keys, I'm stuck:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.3.0 (3df822b)
  on Internal Runner (079281fd)
Using Docker executor with image 1drop/docker:git ...
Using docker image sha256:b9cf0ca386341048f8696d950123e20b5d6583c190f266aacb25b6d3d4736028 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image 1drop/docker:git ...
Using docker image 1drop/docker:git ID=sha256:966d107d59806ab1a3aa2229618858b5141e2c7bb183dd9f4dfaafdca4d51774 for build container...
Running on runner-079281fd-project-207-concurrent-0 via srv1...
Fetching changes...
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 17
$ ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"| base64 -d)
Enter passphrase for /dev/fd/63: ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

As you can see I already tried encoding the ed25519 key using base64 if something would go wrong when Gitlab is injecting the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable into the runtime.
The content of the key is fine, I can output it and test it locally and it works. Also if I put a regular RSA key into the SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable, it works perfectly. But on some customer servers I'm required to use ed25519 and I keep getting this "enter passphrase" stuff and I don't know why.

Do I need to install some libraries in order for this to work? My ssh module says it can do ed25519 keys.

Comment: What OpenSSH version is in that system?

Comment: / # apk info openssh
openssh-7.4_p1-r0 description:
Port of OpenBSD's free SSH release

Comment: This is where the the `ssh-add` is run? Is that a docker image?

Comment: Yes, it's the docker-image `1drop/docker:git` which I built from `docker` and adding some small things. It's based on alpine.

Comment: By the way, I accomplished it locally (container with same image) by doing
`export SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="--- ... "`  

`SSH_ASKPASS="/dev/null" ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")`

That worked, but inside of gitlab CI it doesn't. Probably they do some escaping when adding the ENV variables or something like that.

Comment: Some other people also had that issue https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1 but couldn't solve it. I hope somebody here can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation has been updated. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/

```
  ##
  ## Add the SSH key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
  ## We're using tr to fix line endings which makes ed25519 keys work
  ## without extra base64 encoding.
  ## https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/issues/1#note_48526556
  ##
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
```

Using this command worked for me.

Comment: It giving me error as Enter passphrase for (stdin): ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: @JigsVirani that's because you created your key with a passphrase. Create another one and make sure you only input your email.

Comment: The link is dead and I think the documentation has been updated again. Please check and update. Thanks.